# Bootstrap- 4 :-Toggle between two div elements, where one div hides when other div is active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Explaination:-**

I am two buttons **Yes** and **No**

Lets say there are two `div` elements as follows

`<div id="div1">Yes button clicked</div>`

`<div id="div2">No button clicked</div>`

If a user clicks **Yes**,`id="div1"` is shown, while hiding the `id="div2"`.

When the user clicks **No**, `id="div2"` is shown, while hiding the `id="div1"`.

I can achieve that with `collapse` in `Bootstrap`, but the thing is when I click **Yes**, the `div` element for **No** is also available.

**Here is the actual code that I tried so far**

```
 <div class="jumbotron m-4" id="accordion">
  <h1 class="display-5 text-center">Do you remember your current password?</h1>
  <p class="text-center">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#password_reset_form" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="password_reset_form" id="rp_yes">Yes</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#not_rem_p" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="not_rem_p" id="rp_no">No</button>
</p>
</div>


<div class="collapse" id="password_reset_form">//Form to change password</div>
<div class="collapse" id="not_rem_p"><a href="#">Use Forgot Password instead</a></div>
```

So, when I click **yes**, the *form* shows up , but when I click **no**, *forgot password* link is also shown **along with** the reset password form. I want to show one of them at a time. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `jQuery script` provided by Bootstrap to achieve what you want --

```
<p>                    ---->>Updated here
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="rp_yes">Yes</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="rp_no">No</button>
</p>
```

**Script**

```
$('#rp_yes').click(function(){
            $("#password_reset_form").collapse('show');
                 $("#not_rem_p").collapse('hide');
        });
        $('#rp_no').click(function(){
                $("#not_rem_p").collapse('show');
                $("#password_reset_form").collapse('hide');
        });
```

`$(<selector>).collapse('options')` is the required change here. More documentations here [Bootstrap Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#:%7E:text=Bootstrap%E2%80%99s%20collapse%20class%20exposes%20a%20few%20events%20for,user%20%28will%20wait%20for%20CSS%20transitions%20to%20complete%29.)

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily achieve what you want by first hiding all with class `.collapse` and then afterwards show.

I.e. for buttons

```
onClick="$('.collapse').hide();$('#div1').show();"
```